# Confused on this wire config

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I am trying to install (2) Lutron Caseta Wireless Switches to replace two legacy light switches. This is my first attempt at replacing a light switch. When looking inside, I am a bit confused on the wiring configuration:
-Why are there four white wires that are just joined together? Do they serve a purpose?
-Why is only one switch grounded?
-Why is there a connection from one switch direct to the other (capped with a yellow connector in this image)[image]

Comment: Both switches should be grounded. Someone was just lazy or careless.

Comment: Sorry @A.I.Breveleri our edits collided.   IMO the second ground doesn't matter if the cover plate is metal.  But it might matter to the smart switch.

Answer (score 1):

The whites in the back of the box are very important.  They are *neutral*, and you wouldn't have a circuit without them.  Also it's rather fortunate they are there, because a good quality smart switch will require them.

On both switches, you have 2 wires going to a single screw terminal.  This is nothing but a lazy shortcut in wiring.   Those multiple wires could be replaced by a *pigtail*, in which case the wiring would be easier to understand.   It looks like that hoppy wire is the "always hot" wire, and is commonly** color coded black, which it happens to be.  The solo black wires are switched-hots going up to the lights, and they are commonly** color coded red, and I'd mark them with red tape.  I'dThis will make it even easier to understand.

Most people, even freshmen like yourself, don't need *equipment safety ground* explained to them.  The only thing you might need to know is when ground has insulation, it is green, or green/yellow stripe.

** that is common practice. The law only specifies colors for ground and neutral (white or gray).  Legally a hot can be any other color.  In this wiring, the switched-hot is black because they are using pre-made cables and don't have a choice for color.  That's what tape is for.

Comment: Sorry A.I. Your edit collided with my adding paragraph 2

Comment: Your edit covers my contribution. Plus, you said it better.